# adding values in array where id's are the same php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array.  In the array there are 2 [id] values that are the same.
I would like to be able to add the [score] of these elements and merge the elements where the [id] are the same.  Is this possible?

```
[0] =>  
        [id] => 9428 
        [auth] => manual 
        [firstname] => Tariq 
        [lastname] => Essop 
        [score] => 75.000000000 
        [timecreated] => 1366093740 
        [courseid] => 215 
        [itemname] => 2164 Date of assessment and dispute resolution 
        [itemid] => 750 ) 

[1] => 
        [id] => 9428 
        [auth] => manual 
        [firstname] => Tariq 
        [lastname] => Essop 
        [score] => 75.000000000 
        [timecreated] => 1366100428 
        [courseid] => 215 
        [itemname] => 2168 Cross-border loans and intellectual property 
        [itemid] => 751 )

[2] => 
        [id] => 6258 
        [auth] => manual 
        [firstname] => Tariq 
        [lastname] => Essop 
        [score] => 75.000000000 
        [timecreated] => 1366100428 
        [courseid] => 215 
        [itemname] => 2168 Cross-border loans and intellectual property 
        [itemid] => 752 )
```

Comment: How `itemname` from elements with same ID would merge?

Comment: @Shikiryu  Itemname is not important, the value can be overwritten by the first value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = array();

foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (!isset($data[$item['id']])) {
        $data[$item['id']] = $item;
    } else {
        // do whatever you need to do to $data[$item['id']], e.g.:
        $data[$item['id']]['score'] += $item['score'];
    }
}
```